# WFS Query with BBOX

Tags: arcgis-server, wfs, extents

I am getting frustrated trying to get data from an WFS service.
Here is the service located: http://nvpub.vic-metria.nu/arcgis/services/N2000_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

I am getting features with a `GetFeature` request, but when I try to add `BBOX` parameter I get either no result or wrong features.

Here is an example curl request:

`curl "http://nvpub.vic-metria.nu/arcgis/services/N2000_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=N2000_WFS:N2000&outputFormat=GEOJSON&BBOX=67.03244,19.63500,68.07416,22.52898"`

WGS84 DD (LAT, LONG)
I want results from northern Sweden but I am not getting it.

How do I do this?

Comment: are you certain there is data in the region you requested?

Answer (score 1):

As you are asking for the bounding box in a projection that is not the layer default CRS (urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3006) you need to tell server what projection you are using so a URL like:

```
http://nvpub.vic-metria.nu/arcgis/services/N2000_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer?service=wfs&request=getFeature&typeNames=N2000_WFS:N2000&bbox=67.03244,19.63500,68.07416,22.52898,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
```

but it just times out

So I tried converting your bounding box to the default CRS

```
http://nvpub.vic-metria.nu/arcgis/services/N2000_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer?service=wfs&request=getFeature&typeNames=N2000_WFS:N2000&bbox=7442512.461951639,701674.7786485886,7570250.520925573,813087.8345357453
```

which also returns an empty feature collection:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:N2000_WFS="https://nvpub.vic-metria.nu/arcgis/services/N2000_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" timeStamp="2021-03-27T17:11:57Z" numberMatched="unknown" numberReturned="0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd https://nvpub.vic-metria.nu/arcgis/services/N2000_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer http://nvpub.vic-metria.nu/arcgis/services/N2000_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer?service=wfs%26version=2.0.0%26request=DescribeFeatureType">
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

So, I dumped the capabilities URL into QGIS to see what was going on and all I get are timeouts, so I think it is an unwell WFS server and you should probably ask the operator to fix it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. I will ask them!